# Git apply some modifications after several pull

Tags: git

I use an open source software developed by another developer. I git pull every three months to keep up to date, and need to have some small modifications of his code, always the same.

The modification I need is changing a few paths in the build files to match my own environment.

I have thought about a few solutions to solve that problem:

1. I created a different branch called `my_changes`. Every three months, I git pull the changes for the developer into the `master` branch. Then I run `git merge my_changes` from the `master` branch.

That seems like a really bad solutions, as this is messy and error prone

2. I have explored using git patches, but I am not sure this is the right way to do it? I have no experience with git patches
3. I could simply modify the files I need modify, create a branch `master_with_my_changes` and try to pull the other dev's changes on top of it, somehow.

What is the right way to go about this very simple problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run this once: `git branch -u origin/master my_changes`

Run this to pull changes: `git pull --rebase`